# Can I include an https resource from a page loaded by http

Tags: http, web, https

I will host my site using http and in the web page, I want to include some resource ( css, js ) from some https site.

Is that allowed (seems to me it is fine)?

Does any specification discuss this?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's allowed. I'm not sure that it's documented in a specification anywhere; it seems more like a browser policy.